# Drools - Rules within different agenda groups

Tags: drools

I have various sets of rule files with rules belonging to different agenda groups. I load all the rule files at the beginning. When I try to fire rules for a specific agenda group, rules under the other agenda groups are getting evaluated as well.

```
session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Agenda Group Name").setFocus()
session.insert("fact1")...
```

Here session is statefull.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Essentially, need to control which agenda groups to fire and which ones to not.

Comment: You control the firing of the rules  by calling `session.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("Agenda Group Name").setFocus()' - as you apparently know.